# Toggle Not Functioning As Expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, toggle

The following code works just fine:

```
function toggleVis(id) {

  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.display == 'block')
    e.style.display = 'none';
  else
    e.style.display = 'block'; 
}

<label onclick='toggleVis("weapon-set");' for='checkboxes-0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes' id='checkboxes-0' value='1'>
  Weapon
</label>

<fieldset id='weapon-set' class='toggle'><legend>Weapon</legend></fieldset>
```

I can click either the checkbox or the label to toggle the visibility of the fieldset on or off.  However, if I set the initial visibility of the fieldset to display:none; using CSS selectors, I can ONLY use the checkbox to toggle the visibility.  Any ideas on how to make the label toggle work properly?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @epascarello Sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith Well, I'd like it to work when I click the label, like it does if the fieldset isn't set to display:none initially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a class to toggle the visibilty

```js
function toggleVis(id) {
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  elem.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden { display : none }
```

```html
<label  for='checkboxes-0'>
  <input type='checkbox' name='checkboxes' id='checkboxes-0' value='1' onchange='toggleVis("weapon-set");'>
  Weapon
</label>

<fieldset id='weapon-set' class='toggle'><legend>Weapon</legend></fieldset>
```

You can also base it off the checkbox state instead of default state.

Comment: It still doesn't toggle when the label is clicked instead of the checkbox though.